# How to clear Evaluate result on IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, evaluate

I am using the evaluate window to test some expressions but when I execute it, the result is concatenated with the previous result, is there a way to clean it?

I tryed to close and open IDE but it always happens. Can someone help me?

`contract.append(formatedData.substring(8));`

The result is past consults concatenated with actual:

`01214401210121012108.15.44.4208.15.44.4208.15.44.4208.15.44.42`